# Selector It works on all the buttons at once

Tags: android, background-image, android-button, xml-drawable

I have three buttons with

```
android:background="@drawable/selector_button_dove_gray"
```

Selector code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_mine_shaft" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_dove_gray"/>
</selector>
```

But background change on all buttons, when i click one of them. What i need do for correctly work?

Comment: I'm not sure but try this: 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_mine_shaft" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_dove_gray" android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>

Comment: Please post (i fyou can) the complete content of the xml files. It will be helpfull to all. Thanks